# FactoryGirl: How do I create a factory once and use it everywhere even in associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I have two factories defined (there are others not shown) as follows:

Jobseekers & SavedSearch

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job_seeker do
    type Role::JOB_SEEKER_TYPE
    commenced_on { rand(60).days.ago }
  end

  factory :saved_search do
    title   { Faker::Company.bs + ' title' }
    association :job_seeker
    saved_on    { rand(10).days.ago }
  end
end
```

If I instantiate a jobseeker using the FactoryGirl step definitions like so:

```
Given 1 job seeker exists
```

Then when I do:

```
Given 3 saved searches exist
```

I get 3 saved_searches OK, but all with new job_seekers (as it should be, as expressed) - but not what I want.

All searches must reference the first job seeker already instantiated.

How can I reference the original job_seeker factory (already instantiated) in the association with :saved_search.

Using:

```
cucumber-1.1.9
factory_girl_rails-1.7.0
factory_girl-2.6.4
rails-3.0.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does what it's supposed to.
job_seeker { JobSeeker.first || association(:job_seeker) } fixed the problem.